# Joining two dataframes using col1 OR col2, then adding result

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes that I'd like to conditionally merge.

df1:

```
   Location      `Sub Location` Date           n
   <chr>         <chr>          <chr>      <int>
 1 AREA 1        Bore Drain     2014-04-21    15
 2 AREA 1        Bore Drain     2014-04-23     2
 3 AREA 1        Bore Drain     2014-04-24     6
 4 AREA 1        Bore Drain     2015-04-04     6
 5 AREA 1        Bore Drain     2015-04-08     8
 6 AREA 1        Bore Drain     2015-04-09     9
 7 AREA 1        Bore Drain     2016-03-25    31
 8 AREA 1        Large Dam      2016-03-26     7
 9 AREA 1        Bore Drain     2016-04-01     2
10 AREA 1        Bore Drain     2016-04-02     6
```

and df2:

```
   Location `Sub Location`   StartDate  EndDate    Totals
   <chr>  <chr>               <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>
 1 AREA 1 Homestead           2013-03-29 2013-03-30      0
 2 AREA 1 Bore Drain          2014-04-21 2014-04-21      0
 3 AREA 1 Homestead           2014-04-17 2014-04-18      0
 4 AREA 1 Cottage             2014-04-21 2014-04-22      0
 5 AREA 1 Bore Drain          2014-04-23 2014-04-24      0
 6 AREA 1 Bore Drain          2015-04-03 2015-04-04      0
 7 AREA 1 Homestead           2015-04-03 2015-04-04      0
 8 AREA 1 Bore Drain          2015-04-08 2015-04-09      0
 9 AREA 1 Cottage             2015-04-08 2015-04-09      0
10 AREA 1 Homestead           2016-03-25 2016-03-25      0
```

What I'd like to do is check for each entry in df1, if `Date` matches either `StartDate` OR `EndDate`, AND the `location` and `Sub Location` are the same. If this is the case, I'd like `n` in df1 to be added to `Totals` in df2

I've tried using `ifelse()` or going through every entry in a for loop, but I haven't been able to get it working. Any suggestions are appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge twice, first matching `Date` to `StartDate`, then to `EndDate`. For cases where `StartDate == EndDate`, it will merge in the same row from `df1` twice, so delete the second `n` value. Then add the two merged-in `n` columns to `Totals`.

```
library(dplyr)

merged <- df2 %>%
  left_join(df1, by = c("StartDate" = "Date", "Location", "SubLocation")) %>%
  left_join(df1, by = c("EndDate" = "Date", "Location", "SubLocation")) %>%
  mutate(
    n.y = ifelse(StartDate == EndDate, NA, n.y),
    Totals = rowSums(across(c(Totals, n.x, n.y)), na.rm = TRUE),
    n.x = NULL,
    n.y = NULL
  )
  
merged
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   Location SubLocation StartDate  EndDate    Totals
   <chr>    <chr>       <date>     <date>      <dbl>
 1 AREA 1   Homestead   2013-03-29 2013-03-30      0
 2 AREA 1   BoreDrain   2014-04-21 2014-04-21     15
 3 AREA 1   Homestead   2014-04-17 2014-04-18      0
 4 AREA 1   Cottage     2014-04-21 2014-04-22      0
 5 AREA 1   BoreDrain   2014-04-23 2014-04-24      8
 6 AREA 1   BoreDrain   2015-04-03 2015-04-04      6
 7 AREA 1   Homestead   2015-04-03 2015-04-04      0
 8 AREA 1   BoreDrain   2015-04-08 2015-04-09     17
 9 AREA 1   Cottage     2015-04-08 2015-04-09      0
10 AREA 1   Homestead   2016-03-25 2016-03-25      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
df2$Totals <- rowSums(t(apply(df2, 1, function(x) 
                ifelse(x["Location"] == df1$Location & 
                       x["`Sub Location`"] == df1$"`Sub Location`" & 
                      (x["StartDate"] == df1$Date | x["EndDate"] == df1$Date), 
                         df1$n, 0))))
df2
   Location `Sub Location`  StartDate    EndDate Totals
1    AREA 1      Homestead 2013-03-29 2013-03-30      0
2    AREA 1     Bore Drain 2014-04-21 2014-04-21     15
3    AREA 1      Homestead 2014-04-17 2014-04-18      0
4    AREA 1        Cottage 2014-04-21 2014-04-22      0
5    AREA 1     Bore Drain 2014-04-23 2014-04-24      8
6    AREA 1     Bore Drain 2015-04-03 2015-04-04      6
7    AREA 1      Homestead 2015-04-03 2015-04-04      0
8    AREA 1     Bore Drain 2015-04-08 2015-04-09     17
9    AREA 1        Cottage 2015-04-08 2015-04-09      0
10   AREA 1      Homestead 2016-03-25 2016-03-25      0
```

##### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Location = c("AREA 1", "AREA 1", "AREA 1", "AREA 1", 
"AREA 1", "AREA 1", "AREA 1", "AREA 1", "AREA 1", "AREA 1"), 
    ``Sub Location`` = c("Bore Drain", "Bore Drain", "Bore Drain", 
    "Bore Drain", "Bore Drain", "Bore Drain", "Bore Drain", "Large Dam", 
    "Bore Drain", "Bore Drain"), Date = c("2014-04-21", "2014-04-23", 
    "2014-04-24", "2015-04-04", "2015-04-08", "2015-04-09", "2016-03-25", 
    "2016-03-26", "2016-04-01", "2016-04-02"), n = c(15L, 2L, 
    6L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 31L, 7L, 2L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

df2 <- structure(list(Location = c("AREA 1", "AREA 1", "AREA 1", "AREA 1", 
"AREA 1", "AREA 1", "AREA 1", "AREA 1", "AREA 1", "AREA 1"), 
    ``Sub Location`` = c("Homestead", "Bore Drain", "Homestead", 
    "Cottage", "Bore Drain", "Bore Drain", "Homestead", "Bore Drain", 
    "Cottage", "Homestead"), StartDate = c("2013-03-29", "2014-04-21", 
    "2014-04-17", "2014-04-21", "2014-04-23", "2015-04-03", "2015-04-03", 
    "2015-04-08", "2015-04-08", "2016-03-25"), EndDate = c("2013-03-30", 
    "2014-04-21", "2014-04-18", "2014-04-22", "2014-04-24", "2015-04-04", 
    "2015-04-04", "2015-04-09", "2015-04-09", "2016-03-25"), 
    Totals = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer `case_when`. To me it is easier to understand. First `full_join` the 2 dataframes, then use `case_when` to the conditions you specified. Then `distinct` to remove duplicates. `group_by` to add up and `distinct` again to remove duplicates

```
df1 %>%
  full_join(df2) %>%
  mutate(n = as.numeric(n),
         Totals = as.numeric(Totals)) %>%
  mutate(Totals = case_when(
    Date == StartDate | Date == EndDate ~ Totals + n,
    TRUE ~ Totals
  )) %>% 
  distinct(Location,Sub.Location,StartDate,EndDate, Totals,.keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-n, -Date) %>% 
  group_by(Location, Sub.Location, StartDate) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  mutate(Totals = sum(Totals)) %>% 
  distinct(Location,Sub.Location,StartDate,EndDate, .keep_all = TRUE)
```